# Why does the multiplication in a division algebra depends on every component?

Tags: quaternions, division-algebras, octave, complex-multiplication

In a division algebra A over $\mathbb{R}$ we have this multiplication (A isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$)
$$\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}:(x,y)\mapsto y=x\cdot y$$
where every component of z depends bilinear on every component of x and y. Why is it impossible that z just depends on every odd component of x or something like that? Is it because otherwise we get a problem with a zero divisor?

Comment: If $a\cdot x=a\cdot x'$ and $x\ne x'$, then $a\cdot(x-x')=0$ but $x-x'\ne 0$. So, yes, you answered your own question: we get a problem with a zero divisor.

Comment: What anon said, but phrased differently: for a fixed non-zero vector $x$ the linear mapping $y\mapsto x\cdot y$ must be onto. The spaces are finite dimensional, so "injective <=> surjective" by rank-nullity.